# Microsoft flow:ForbiddenError-403, when trying to create private channel in MS teams

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, documentation, http-status-code-403

I am trying to make an HTTP request into MS teams in order to create  private channel like in the following example.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

In order to authenticate it, the HTTP request, with option of "Active Directory oauth", it needs some info. 1) Cliend ID, 2) Tenant ID, 3) Audience & 4) Credential Type.
Therefore, I register an app at Registration App Azure page, where I have all this info + create a secret to provide it. In addition I give permissions. My task is to create/delete private channels and add/drop members. Why is there a 403-statusCode error called it "Forbidden"?

Also, in a lot of docs, a token is mentioned, but I donot know how to create&use it, as there is also not an accurate, step-by-step example for all this authentication/authorization/permissions.

Can someone provide that? Or explain why is that error there, as the info microsoft.docs is inefficient?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/resolve-auth-errors

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/resolve-auth-errors

Comment: First things first, I would start first understand the basics of Identity before jumping into Graph API programming. In addition, if i want to just play with the above Graph calls then you can use Microsoft Graph explorer or POSTMAN (with exact same AAD flow that you're doing at your app) to see whether you can repro the scenario or not.

Comment: May I know what did you do to request the graph api before you get 403 forbidden response ?

Comment: @HuryShen in the first link I provide in the start of my question, there are 2 examples if you scroll down. Exactly these 2 scripts.

Comment: Does this help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 403 error indicates that your token lacks the permission to call the api. Each api document clearly explains what permissions are required to call the api.
Take the [create channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) as an example: It lists the permissions you need to call the api. These permissions are arranged from small to large, and you only need to select one of them. Then you need to add the permission to your application, and then grant the **administrator consent** for the permission.

Go to **Azure portal**>**Azure AD**>**App registrations**>**your app**>**API permissions**.

[image]

What you need to note is that permissions are divided into **application permissions** and **delegated permissions**.

> Delegated permission is the authorization of the service principal on
> behalf of the user. It usually involves user interaction. If you need
> to log in to the user, you can choose to grant the permission, and
> then you need to use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to obtain an access token.
>
> Application permission is the authorization of the service principal
> on their own behalf. It is usually used in a daemon where no user is
> logged in. If you do not need to log in to the user, you can choose to
> grant the permission, and then you need to use the
> [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to obtain an access token.

Comment: The problem was that I could not "grant consent" to some permissions, as I was not admin. So, I did ask from the admin and now it is working. Pretty basic stuff, but still important to have it clear. Thanks @Carl Zhao.